# How can I make a variable in a viewModel to an overvable variable? (knockout)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, knockout.js

[image]

As the screenshot shows, there is a viewModel called applications in my page and it has a variable named "isShortlisted" that indicates whether the application is shortlisted or not. It is declared as follows:

```
self.applications = ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.ApplicationCompatibilities.Select(o => o.JsonForm)) || []);
```

and I need to set isShortlisted to observable because I want my button that has this condition

```
<form id="shortlistForm" data-bind="style: { display: application.isShortlisted === false ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}>

<form id="unshortlistForm" data-bind="style: { display: application.isShortlisted === true ? 'inline-block' : 'none'}>

(the form above shows up when "isShortlisted" is false and the one below shows when it's true(when clicked) )
```

to show changes immediately when "isShortlisted" value is changed (and only observable updates the change immediately)

What I tried to do is:

```
self.isShortlistedObservable = ko.observable(self.applications.application.isShortlisted);
```

and gives me an error

```
Cannot read property 'isShortlisted' of undefined
```

To summarize, I can I make that variable observable so that it updates the status whenever the value is changed? Plz tell me the right syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all of the pertinent code blocks it's difficult to give you a proper answer but here are a few hints that might help you.

Your particular error is telling you that `self.applications.application` is undefined. This makes sense because self.applications is an observable array so what you should have done was this: `self.applications()[0].application.isShortlisted`.

As for the `isShortlisted` observable, you can declare your new observable directly on `self` as you've done although I would recommend you instead decorate your application VM with the observable. Like so:

```
var vm = self.applications()[0].application;
vm.isShortlistedObservable = ko.observable(vm.isShortlisted);
```

With regards to the HTML binding, I'd recommend you use the `visible` binding as it will do exactly what you want with less code. Note that I'm under the assumption that the KO context in your template is `vm` as shown above so it should look like this:

```
<form id="shortlistForm" data-bind="visible: !isShortlisted()">
<form id="unshortlistForm" data-bind="visible: isShortlisted">
```

Keep in mind this will work so long as you update the observable value and not just the native JS property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I do this, I dont get an error anymore, but I don't get how it will work. "self.applications()[0].application.isShortlisted" will return "isShortlisted" of the first object. How am I supposed to access the other ones? Because I am assuming to make the shortlistForm visible by making "isShortlisted" to true

Comment: This is the part of your question that I don't completely understand. Perhaps if you added a bit more description or the pertinent code blocks I could better answer your question?